# Detect User Mouse Moves Outside and Inside the Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect user if he is not using his computer by tracking mouse events? Do you know How can I achieve this using JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Unless you're building a native desktop application running a JavaScript engine that allows such a thing you can't track the mouse outside the browser (or on other pages).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure tracking mouse movements outside the browser is possible. You track this type of thing by using event listeners and mounting the listener to an html element. in your case you would mount a `mousemove` listener to the window to track movement across the whole page. But outside of the browser window their is nothing that JS can mount an event listener to their for leaving no option to track mouse movement outside the browser. (could be wrong though, seems creepy if its possible)